# Name of theorem about the rank of roots of a rational function

Tags: polynomials, roots, fractions

Suppose you have a rational function, of the form `H(x)=B(x)/A(x)`. It's differential is of the form `H'(x)=(B'(x)*A(x)-B(x)*A'(x))/(A(x))^2`. It is trivial to prove that, if `k` is a root of `B(x)` or `A(x)` with rank `r`, `r>=2`, then `k` is also a root of `H'(x)`'s numerator, `B'(x)*A(x)-B(x)*A'(x)`, with rank at least `r-1`. Is there a theorem that states this exact thing?

The reason I need this is, I am going to take an exam soon, and in a specific part of the exam this observation would be very useful. But I will have to prove it by hand during the exam, and time will be very limited, so I was wondering if there is already a name for this to reference it directly and get on with it.

EDIT: Had erroneously named the desired form "polynomial fraction", instead of the right "rational function".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name for "polynomial fractions" is *rational functions*.

I don't think there's a special name for this result.  Closely related is the fact that a polynomial and its derivative are relatively prime if and only if there's no repeated root.

Anyway, I would just state it and use it when necessary.